# Bool types in Entity Framework+Oracle

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, oracle11g, database-migration

I have an application with a tier domain containing boolean types in the models. The current database is SQL Server 2012, but I need to migrate to Oracle 11g.

Oracle doesn't accept boolean types, however, so what is the best low impact migration option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle offers [support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/index-084442.html) for migrating from third parties to an Oracle database.